# Trigger a simple aws-cli command based on Cloudwatch log event

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-msk

Folks,
Is there a way to run a simple aws-cli command when a specific metric gets triggered in Cloudwatch?

I know one logic is from Cloudwatch --> SNS --> Lambda, but what I am looking here is can I just run the command from CLoudwatch itself?

The command I am looking here is MSK Partition increase command.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the AWS CLI command from CloudWatch. Setup an EventBeidge rule to trigger Lambda, a StepFunction or SNS to Lambda like you mention. Step Functions are particularly great because they can call many of the AWS APIs with no code, and sounds like what you may ne looking for  Even though you are not looking for the orchestraion piece of Step Functions, I do not think it would be overkill to trigger Step Function from EventBridge rule on some metric threshold and use Step Function to call the AWS API you want.